# WIX buttons / pop up dialogs

Tags: wix, wix3

Is there a way to add a button to a WIX custom UI? More importantly as well how do I make it spawn a dialog?

Something like this,

```
<Control Id="ConfigureDatabase" Type="Button" Width="70" X="150" Y="210" Height="18"/>
```

I get an error when doing that,

The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2885

I am trying to make a pop up dialog which will allow a user to enter in some databases settings. Why I want to make it pop up is because most users wont case about these settings. Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  I recommend you take a look at [Chapter 8](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/interactions/) of this extensive [WiX tutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/).  Blatantly copied from section 3 of chapter 8:

```
<Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="[ButtonText_Cancel]">
  <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
</Control>
```